# How to get output from google microphone search to python script?

Tags: python, search, microphone, box

I am currently using google to transcribe speech to text. But it is too slow. I would like to use the google microphone search box output instead (since it is almost real time). I have been reading Selenium examples but can't find anything returning the voice search text.

My existing code:

```
import time, wave, pymedia.audio.sound as sound
import pyautogui
import pyaudio,os
import speech_recognition as sr


f1= wave.open( 'HelloWorld.wav', 'rb' )
sampleRate1= f1.getframerate()
channels1= f1.getnchannels()
format= sound.AFMT_S16_LE
snd1= sound.Output( sampleRate1, channels1, format )
s1= f1.readframes( 800000 )


def hello():
    snd1.play( s1 )


def mainfunction(source):
    audio = r.listen(source)
    user = (r.recognize_google(audio, language = "en-us", show_all=False))
    print(user)
    if user == "hello world":
        residential()

    else:
        pass    

try:
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            while 1:
                r.pause_threshold = 0.5
                r.energy_threshold = 150
                r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration = 0.5)
                mainfunction(source)
```